# Possible to check if a webrquest comes from a click or was typed in the addressbar ? | Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to check if someone clicked a link on a website oder typed it into the addressbar and presses enter.

Is there maybe a flag or something?

I need to do this in the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish these two events? What about bookmarklets, scripted navigation, page access by command line, etc? You can't get the origin of a request via the WebRequest API, but you *can* get this information from the [`chrome.history`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html) API. Another possibly relevant API is the [`chrome.omnibox`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html).